# How can I pass a list of strings in the URL in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, postman

To pass single parameters in the URL I use the following in Postman:

`http://localhost:3000/api/prices/:shopId`

That works!

Now, What I want to do is, to replace the shopId with **List of shopIds**.

Do have any ideas about how can I make this happen?

---

Pseudo Code:

`URL for shopId = 1: http://localhost:3000/api/prices/1`

`URL for shopId = 2: http://localhost:3000/api/prices/2`

What should I do to get the both shopId 1 and 2 in single API response?

Comment: Hey Giannis! Welcome to stack overflow. I am still unable to comprehend what you want to do? Can you explain things in a stretch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best shot is to pass the elements of your array delimited with a character that won't ever be in any of the words (for example, a comma).

Take this snippet for example:

```
app.get('api/prices/:ids', function(req, res){
    var ids = req.params.ids.split(',');
    console.log(ids); //['shopId1', 'shopdId2']
})
```

Endpoint that you reach with a GET request to:

`http://localhost:3000/api/prices/shopId1,shopId2`

Comment: I want to handle this with an undefined number of shopIds. Is it possible?

Comment: Definitely, Node.js arrays don't have a predefined length limit. With the same `app.get` snippet, calling `http://localhost:3000/api/prices/shopId1,shopId2,shopId3,shopId4,shopId5,shopId6` will work just fine. You can add as many shopIds as you want, until the URL becomes too big to handle for either Express, your load balancer if you have one, or Web navigators.

Comment: Glad it did! Code safely.

Answer (score 4):

For your requirement, I can think of a couple of alternatives, which I feel are better practices than what you mentioned.

1. Send it in the body using any of `POST` or `PUT`.

   `URL: http://localhost:3000/api/prices/shopIds`

   `Body: { shopIds: [1, 2, 3, 4] }`

You can retrieve the IDs like,

```
const { shopIds } = req.body // shopIds = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or

```
const shopIds = req.body.shopIds // shopIds = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

2. If you want to use `GET`, then use query parameter

   `URL: POST http://localhost:3000/api/prices/shopIds?ids=1,2,3,4`

Here you can retrieve the IDs as a string and then convert them to array,

```
const ids = req.query.ids.split(','); // ids = [1 ,2, 3, 4]
```

---

If you still want to use it the way you mentioned, it's already answered. Use that method!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to handle this with an undefined number of shopIds. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes! It's better to use the method 1 then! Try making a POST or PUT request and inside body add shopIds, any number you want. It would be better if you add it as array!

Comment: I need to use the Get method! I found the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alternative answer:

```
URL: GET http://localhost:3000/api/prices/shopIds?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4
```

And then in your express get endpoint:

```
let ids = req.body.id
```

However, ids might be a string or a list depending on if there is one or more id in the parameter list. Not sure how to treat this in a good way.